# Error in Compiled exe, but running in m file MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function, compiler-construction, compiler-errors, maple

I have build a program that run properly in m file MATLAB. but when I compile to exe using Matlab compiler, some function didn't work. here is the error command window show on matlab execute program

```
undefined function or method 'maple' for input arguments of type 'char'
error in ==> function_a at 5
```

codes on function_a.m is

```
function function_a(msg)
format long

%parameter p & q
maple('z1:=',randint(1,1,[12 20])); %these run  in m.file, but not in exe compile
p=maple('nextprime(z1)');
p=str2double(p);
```

is there any solution for that?please need your advice, many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have tried to compile the version from exactly this sourcecode and that you call it twice with exactly the same input, it appears that MATLAB simply does not realize that the function `maple` will be used by you.

I have had this before with some project, eventually I decided to use the 'add additional resource to project' option in `deploytool`.

Depending on your needs you can either just add the function, or the folder containing this function.

Comment: Hi, Mr @dennis-jaheruddin could you please tell me using some sample code? that it relevance with my code?

Comment: @adi I am not proposing a code change. When you use `deploytool` you can just point and click in it to add these extra resources. Just give it a try and be specific if you get stuck somewhere.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin This would usually be a correct answer to this question, but in this case the issue is that the `maple` command is part of Symbolic Toolbox, which is not supported by MATLAB Compiler. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The command `maple` is from Symbolic Toolbox, which is [not supported](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/ineligible_programs/) by MATLAB Compiler. You will not be able to successfully compile and run your program.

What's happened is that the `maple` command is not allowed to be compiled, so when the .exe runs, it can't find the function `maple`, and gives you the error you're seeing. It would be nice if MATLAB gave you a more informative error message, but it seems it doesn't.

Comment: Hi Mr. @sam-roberts is there any solution for change code 'maple' in m file to another code that support in exe according in my codes above?

Comment: If what you want is to do what your code example does, i.e. find a random number and then the next prime after it then yes, you could easily write pure MATLAB (i.e. with no Symbolic Toolbox) commands to do that, which would compile with no problem. But if you want to access general Maple functionality in a compiled application then no, there is no way to do that. The `maple` command in MATLAB actually calls the Maple software directly. To compile it, the compiled application would need to contain a full copy of Maple, which would be against the licensing agreement for that software.

Comment: Hi Mr. @sam-roberts what is the similar codes for maple in matlab? so that I can use for change the function to replace maple. please need your advices

Comment: @adi Maple is a large application with many capabilities. If there is a specific capability of Maple that you need to implement directly in MATLAB because of a need to compile it, ask a (separate) question about that. It is not possible (without years of work, anyway) to replicate the whole of Maple within MATLAB.